# Transparencies Affecting Export

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, normals, collada

I have a very complex model that unfortunately I cannot share. It is fully texturized and looks perfect in the 3D window. However, the material and texture assignments seem to have something wrong. The vehicle is allowing all exterior surfaces to be transparent and I can see inside.

Everything was fine until I tried running an alpha channel on my one texture. Every part is texturized with the same image. It was a png with actual transparent parts on it but mostly with a white background. I've now subbed that out in desperation for a jpg version of the same image but now with white in the background of the transparent parts. But the export is still having the same problem.

I've been messing around with normals of the mesh to see if that'll help and it doesn't seem to be affecting things much.

Are there any similar issues that users or browsers on the exchange have encountered? Is there another way to export a collada without assigning materials? I.e. so it's just what the 3D window sees? Any help would be appreciated.